# Issue with Passing Form Values and Session session_start();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, session

Hi I have an inquiry form with 3 steps

Step 1: small inquiry form (which is currently passing form fields to the step 2 page)

Step 2: full page inquiry form (this form submits and processes data via form processing script - form-process.php which then redirects user to thank you page and sends email to site admin)

Step 3: Thank you page (this page is in Joomla while the above two pages are standalone PHP pages accessed via FTP. )

I'd like to print the form fields (from the form in step 2) to the thank you page.

I am currently using php session to transfer field values from step 1 to step 2 which is working fine, however the same code doesn't bring form value from step 2 to thank you page.

My code is

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);    
session_start();
require_once('validation.class.php');
?>
```

I also use in every single page.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['error_msgs'])){
$_SESSION['error_msgs'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['error_msgs']);  
}
if(isset($_SESSION['sucess'])){
$_SESSION['sucess'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['sucess']);  
}
if(isset($_SESSION['form1data'])){
$_SESSION['form1data'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['form1data']);  
}
?>
```

Can someone help why i am not able to pass values from step 2 to thank you page? I have also put the session() code into the form processing script which fires after step 2 submit button.

Comment: My session code is as below <?php 
error_reporting(0);
session_start();
require_once('validation.class.php');
?>

Comment: does your thank you page has session_start() in the top of it as well as step 2?

Comment: Give us the code for each step and we may be able to help you more effectively.

Comment: Hi here are the codes for each step http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248012/session-value-not-passing-after-redirection-to-the-thank-you-page

Answer (score 0):

i have just added the below code into thank you page and it says below message.
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /tmp/html1jVKJt on line 5
No data

the code i have placed on confirmation page.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['error_msgs'])){
$_SESSION['error_msgs'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['error_msgs']);  
}
if(isset($_SESSION['sucess'])){
$_SESSION['sucess'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['sucess']);  
}
if(isset($_SESSION['form1data'])){
$_SESSION['form1data'] = '';
unset($_SESSION['form1data']);  
}
?>
```

but form field (first name) is still not printing on the confirmation page.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the session is passing from step 1 to step 2 to step 3 (confirmation page) however is not printing the input field.

I am using into confirmation page to  show submitted email.

```
 <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?>"/>
```

Any feedback will be appreciated. thanks