# SESSION value not passing after redirection to the thank you page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to pass `$email` field to thank you page which appears after redirection once user submits the enquiry form.

Its a 2 step enquiry form with thank you page being last.

It seems like the SESSION is live on thank you page however the values are lost. I'd like to get `$email` field posted on the thank you page to an iframe. Please let me know where exactly the session id is going wrong?

Here are the codes:

Step 1: Small Enquiry form

```
 <?php 
 error_reporting(0);
 session_start();
 require_once('validation.class.php');
 if(isset($_REQUEST['btnSubmit']) == 'Next'){
 $obj = new validation();
 $obj->add_fields(trim($_POST['txt_fname']), 'req', 'Enter your first name.');
 $obj->add_fields(trim($_POST['txt_contact']), 'req', 'Enter phone number.');
 $obj->add_fields(trim($_POST['txt_finamount']), 'req', 'Enter the amount.');
 $obj->add_fields(trim($_POST['sel_loantype']), 'req', 'Please select vehicle type.');



$error = $obj->validate();



if($error){

            $error_msg =  "".$error."";     

            $_SESSION['error_msgs'] = $error_msg;

            header("location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."");

            exit(); 

}else{



             $_SESSION['form1data'] = $_REQUEST;

             header("location: quick-quote.php");

             exit();



            /*$fname = trim($_REQUEST["txt_fname"]);

            $surname = trim($_REQUEST["txt_surname"]);

            $phone = trim($_REQUEST["txt_contact"]);

            $finamount = trim($_REQUEST['txt_finamount']);

            $sel_loantype = trim($_REQUEST['sel_loantype']);



            $message = '<html><body>';

            $message .= '<table rules="all"  width="100%" style="border:1px solid #666;" cellpadding="10">';

            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($fname) . "</td></tr>";

            if($surname != ''){

            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Surname:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($surname) . "</td></tr>";

            }

            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($phone) . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Amount to Finance:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($finamount) . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Loan Type:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($sel_loantype) . "</td></tr>";

            $message .= "</table>";

            $message .= "</body></html>";





            $ToEmail       = 'testemail@gmail.com'; 

            $EmailSubject  = "GET A QUICK QUOTE from ".strip_tags($fname); 

            $mailheader    = "From: ".strip_tags($fname)."\r\n"; 

            //$mailheader   .= "Reply-To: ".$_REQUEST["txt_email"]."\r\n"; 

            $mailheader   .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

            $MESSAGE_BODY  = $message;



            if(@mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader)){

                  $_SESSION['sucess'] = "Your message has been sent successfully.";

                  $_SESSION['form1data'] = $_REQUEST;

                  header("location: quick-quote.php");

                  exit; 

            }else{

                  $_SESSION['sucess'] = "Sorry! Your message has not been sent.";

                  $_SESSION['form1data'] = $_REQUEST;

                  header("location: quick-quote.php");

                  exit; 

            }*/

}



 } 



 ?>
```

Step 2 Code:

```
 <?php 
 error_reporting(0);
 session_start();
 require_once('validation.class.php');
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function submitToCRM()
 {
 $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'http://test.com.au/quick-quote/car-finance/quickquote-one.php',
      data: $("#applynowform").serialize(),
      beforeSend: function () {
                                 $("#loadingimg").show();
                              }, 
      success: function (){
        //alert(data);
         window.location.href = "http://www.test.com.au/thank-you";  
      }
});
```

Step 3: The above page sends data to quickquote-one.php form processing script which has below code.

```
 <?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
 { 
  session_start(); 
 } 
 $_SESSION['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

Step 4: thank you page (this page has below code)

```
 <?php
 if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
 { 
 session_start(); 
 $_SESSION['user_email'] = $_POST['email'];
 echo $_SESSION['user_email'];
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: you need `session_start();` before checking `isset($_SESSION)`

Comment: Don't bother checking for a session on the last two pages. Just start your session.

Comment: Hi i have tried removing session_start(); from last two pages however its not printing $email field to the thank you page after it redirects?

Comment: Please note that first page data gets transferred to second page already but its not sending data from second to third page (thank you page) after redirection from submit button.

Comment: HI Dagon. i already have session_start(); before isset($_Session) in all the 3 pages

Comment: then you have it twice, if you $_SESSION is populated - bad idea

Comment: Hi Dagon...so what page should i remove the $session?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

before your

```
session_start();
```

You can also pass the `SID` (session ID) between the pages using the URL to make sure it isn't lost in transition.

```
url: 'http://test.com.au/quick-quote/car-finance/quickquote-one.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>',
```

and

```
window.location.href = "http://www.test.com.au/thank-you?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>";
```

You're losing the session because you're sending the browser to the next URL without a relative path but instead a fully-qualified domain.  This is a security measure to prevent session IDs from being inadvertently sent to the wrong server.

Another small solution would be to use relative paths like `/page.php` instead of `http://www.domain.com/page.php`

### [Read more here (PHP Manual)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Comment: Hi i have just removed exact paths to relative paths and trying to print the email using below code but yet its not bringing the email field. <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ? >"/>

Comment: You need to change the 5th line of your main PHP code.  `if(isset($_REQUEST['btnSubmit']) == 'Next'){`   <-- This will always be FALSE.  you either need to check both or only one but they don't combine conditional statements that way.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {` is what you should have

Answer (score 0):

In step 4 your setting

```
$_SESSION['user_email']
```

again.  If the form has refreshed then your post is empty and you are overwriting the session with an empty value.  Try removing it from step 4 and just leave.

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['user_email']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_email'])) 
 { 
 echo $_SESSION['user_email'];
 } 
 ?>
```

Also you are trying to echo your session email value IF the session is NOT set.  I don't think that will work if the session is actually set..

Comment: Hi I have done this change...To test, I am printing the email via below code on the thank you page but its not printing email. 
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?  >"/>

Comment: Where is quickquote-one.php located?  Is this an external form processor on a remote machine?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is better to start a session in one page and access all the session variables throghout if all the pages are connected to eachother. it will be some thing like we create login page. When user logs in capture alll the required values in a session and can be accessed through out the application even after refresh.

```
$query = "SELECT Useid,UserName,AccountStatus, FullName FROM Users WHERE UserName = :UserName";
```

from this query we can get the session variables easily.

```
 if($login_ok) 
        { 

             //for last visit
            $Month = 2592000 + time(); 
 //this adds 30 days to the current time 
 setcookie(AboutVisit, date("F jS - g:i a"), $Month);
 //last visit ends here.

            $_SESSION['user'] = $row['UserName']; 
            $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['Useid'];
            $_SESSION['fullname'] = $row['FullName'];
            }
```

where ever you need th variable you can use like this

```
$username=$_SESION['user'];
```

I think this will work instead of startign session every time in each page.
Hope it helps